# TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property text as function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, jspdf, sinon-chai

I have a javascript project that imports [jsPDF library](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF)

Contents of pdf.js:

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

createPDF (transcriptString) {
  const transcriptPdfDoc = new jsPDF()

  transcriptPdfDoc.text(transcriptString, 10, 10)
  transcriptPdfDoc.save('test.pdf')
}
```

Contents of pdf.spec.js:

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

beforeEach(() => {
  sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()
})

afterEach(() => {
  sandbox.restore()
})
    
describe('createPDF', () => {
  it('should save transcript PDF', () => {
    const transcriptString = 'test transcript string'
    const jsPdfStub = sandbox.spy(jsPDF.prototype, 'text')
   
    //This function is working OK here in karma 
    pdf.createPDF(transcriptString)
    
    expect(jsPdfStub).to.have.been.called
  })
})
```

The above unit test code give me this error: TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property text as function.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, I would not mind an upvote or checking the accept button.

Comment: Added two full examples of different approaches to test this.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite straight forward: that prototype does not contain a function called `text`, hence the error. I wrote this quick script to verify:

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";

console.dir(jsPDF);
console.log("prototype", jsPDF.prototype);
console.log("prototype has text?", typeof jsPDF.prototype.text !== "undefined");

const pdf = new jsPDF();
console.log(pdf.text);
```

Which outputs this

```
$ node test.js 
[Function: I] {
  API: {
    events: [
      [Array], [Array],
....
....
    RadioButton: [Function: ft],
    CheckBox: [Function: pt],
    TextField: [Function: gt],
    PasswordField: [Function: mt],
    Appearance: {
      CheckBox: [Object],
      RadioButton: [Object],
      createDefaultAppearanceStream: [Function: createDefaultAppearanceStream],
      internal: [Object]
    }
  },
  getPageSize: [Function (anonymous)],
  __bidiEngine__: [Function (anonymous)]
}
prototype { __bidiEngine__: [Function (anonymous)] }
prototype has text? false
[Function (anonymous)]
```

Had a look at [the source](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/blob/master/src/jspdf.js#L209) and there is basically nothing added to the prototype of `jsPdf`. All the plugins and API methods are added/bound to the *instance* when you create a new object by calling the constructor.

### To spy on the `text` method

Instead of trying to find the method on the prototype, you just spy on the instance method.

```
const pdf = new jsPDF();
const spy = sinon.spy(pdf, "text");

const transcriptString = "test transcript string";
pdf.text(transcriptString, 10, 10);

console.log("called?", spy.called); // ==> true
```

In your example of using your own `createPDF()` function *this will not work* as you shield the instance from access in the closure. You need some way of hooking into the instance creation process. There are several ways to "fix" this. One way could be to extract a factory function to create the `jsPDF` instance and a related setter that lets you replace the constructor that gets called. Another way could be to use a ["link seam"](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/) in your test to replace the `jspdf` module.

#### Using a link seam (module replacement)

That would look something like this:

```
import {jsPDF} from 'jspdf';

// later ... in your test
let createdInstance;
let spy;
const createPdf = proxyquire("../src/createPdf", {
      jspdf: {
        jsPDF: (...args) => {
            createdInstance = new jsPDF(...args);
            sinon.spy(createdInstance, 'text');
            return createdInstance;     
        });
      }
});

pdf.createPDF(transcriptString)
    
expect(spy).to.have.been.called
```

This has the advantage of not needed to touch or restructure the original code, but it is very environment specific. `proxyquire` will only work in Node and you need something else for Webpack, a different solution for Vite, Jest, etc.

#### "Manual" DI

If you restructure the code a bit it will make it easier to test regardless of what environment or framework you are using:

```
export class PdfCreator(){
    constructor(opts) {
        this.jsPDF = opts?.stubs?.jsPDF || jsPDF;
    }

    createPdf(text){
        const transcriptPdfDoc = new this.jsPDF()
        transcriptPdfDoc.text(transcriptString, 10, 10)
        transcriptPdfDoc.save('test.pdf')
    }
}

const defaultInstance = new PdfCreator();
export default createPdf = (text) => defaultInstance.createPdf();
```

With this approach you have full control of the creation process. If you want to test the pdf creation, you can just create a `creator = new PdfCreator({stubs: {jsPDF:spy}});` and call `creator.createPdf('foo')` to test it.